# how to enable window.opener.focus() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am writing a Tampermonkey script for personal use.  I use window.open() to open multiple links.  Once I turned the pop up blocker off in settings this worked as expected.  When I tried to get the focus back to the opening window, after all the links had been opened I was unable.  I tried window.opener.focus() and focusing some elements on the parent page.  I understand it is a security issue and browser can ignore this request, but if I'm only using it on my own browser how can I adjust the settings to allow the functionality?

Comment: Have you tried using `postMessage` to tell the opening window to call `window.focus()`?

Comment: Use GM_openInTab to open the tabs in background, see the documentation and examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm got it.  Thank you for your help, it is appreciated.